# Convert Date in R from dash to slash format?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have the following dates:

```
my_dataset <- tibble(my_date = c("03-05-2020", "04-05-2020", "05-05-2020", "06-05-2020"))
```

I would like to create a new column called `nice_dates` which has the date format as: **dd/mm/yyyy** format, so I would end up with something like this:

```
my_date    | nice_dates 
03-05-2020 | 03/05/2020
04-05-2020 | 04/05/2020
05-05-2020 | 05/05/2020
06-05-2020 | 06/05/2020
```

I have tried using the lubridate pacakge but get stuck when defining the new format i know it should be "%d/%m/%Y" however using as.Date() yields NA.

Should i just use gsub instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@ThoVu is almost there.  So for completeness, a much simpler answer with only base R.

Code

```
## input data as before
df <- data.frame(my_date = c("03-05-2020", "04-05-2020", 
                             "05-05-2020", "06-05-2020"))

## create Date objects using base R
df$parsed <- strptime(df$my_date, "%d-%m-%Y")

## format them to spec
df$nice_dates <- format(df$parsed, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Output

```
R> df <- data.frame(my_date = c("03-05-2020", "04-05-2020",
                                "05-05-2020", "06-05-2020"))
R> df$parsed <- strptime(df$my_date, "%d-%m-%Y")
R> df$nice_dates <- format(df$parsed, "%d/%m/%Y")
R> df
     my_date     parsed nice_dates
1 03-05-2020 2020-05-03 03/05/2020
2 04-05-2020 2020-05-04 04/05/2020
3 05-05-2020 2020-05-05 05/05/2020
4 06-05-2020 2020-05-06 06/05/2020
R>
```

My general recommendation is to *never ever* use string manipulations or regular expressions on date inputs when you could use proper date parsers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert dates to date class and then use `format` to get data in the format you want. Since the final output that you want is character you can also use `gsub` here.

```
library(dplyr)

my_dataset %>%
  mutate(nice_dates = format(as.Date(my_date, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%d/%m/%Y'), 
         nice_dates_gsub = gsub('-', '/', my_date))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  my_date    nice_dates nice_dates_gsub
#  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          
#1 03-05-2020 03/05/2020 03/05/2020     
#2 04-05-2020 04/05/2020 04/05/2020     
#3 05-05-2020 05/05/2020 05/05/2020     
#4 06-05-2020 06/05/2020 06/05/2020
```

You can also use `lubridate::dmy(my_date)` to convert data to date class.

Comment: This still makes it as character class - can i not have it as Date type format? - the dmy forces it to be dashes instead of slashes though?

Comment: In R date and times are represented in standard format only. If you change the format of dates they turn into character.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `anytime` package to convert to date format then replace -  with slash /

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(anytime)
my_dataset <- tibble(my_date = c("03-05-2020", "04-05-2020", "05-05-2020", "06-05-2020"))
my_dataset$mice_date <- format(anydate(my_dataset$my_date), '%m/%d/%Y')
#   my_date    mice_date 
#   <chr>      <chr>     
# 1 03-05-2020 03/05/2020
# 2 04-05-2020 04/05/2020
# 3 05-05-2020 05/05/2020
# 4 06-05-2020 06/05/2020
```

Comment: Still weird: Wht use '%d-%m-%Y' only to then call `str_replace_all`? Use _the format you want in the first place_:  `%d/%m/%Y`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks so much for your feedback. You gain my respect.